# How to use values returned from mysql stored function with in() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I have a field named 'dealBusinessLocations' (in a table 'dp_deals') which contain some ids of another table(dp_business_locations) in comma separated format.

```
dealBusinessLocations
----------------------
0,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
```

I need to use this values within an in() function of a query.

like

```
select * from dp_deals as d left join dp_business_locations as b on(b.businessLocID IN (d.dealBusinessLocations) ;
```

Sine mysql doesn't support any string explode function, I have created a stored function

```
delimiter //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BusinessList;
create function BusinessList(BusinessIds text) returns text deterministic
BEGIN
  declare i int default 0;
  declare TmpBid text;
  declare result text default '';
  set TmpBid = BusinessIds;
  WHILE LENGTH(TmpBid) > 0 DO
           SET i = LOCATE(',', TmpBid);
           IF (i = 0)
                   THEN SET i = LENGTH(TmpBid) + 1;
           END IF;
           set result =  CONCAT(result,CONCAT('\'',SUBSTRING(TmpBid, 1, i - 1),'\'\,'));
           SET TmpBid =  SUBSTRING(TmpBid, i + 1, LENGTH(TmpBid));
  END WHILE;
  IF(LENGTH(result) > 0)
      THEN SET result = SUBSTRING(result,1,LENGTH(result)-1);
  END IF;
  return result;
END// 
delimiter  ;
```

The function is working perfectly.

```
mysql> BusinessList( '21,22' )
BusinessList( '21,22' )
-----------------------
'21','22'
```

But the query using the function does not worked either. here is the query.

```
select * from dp_deals as d left join dp_business_locations as b on(b.businessLocID IN (BusinessList(d.dealBusinessLocations)));
```

I have also tried using static value for function argumet, But no use

```
select * from dp_deals as d left join dp_business_locations as b on(b.businessLocID IN (BusinessList('21,22')));
```

It seems that there is some problem with using value returned from the function.

Comment: Normalize your table. Until then, use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read this:

**[`Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?

Yes, it is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**

Then, go and normalize your tables.

---

Now, if you really can't do otherwise, or until you normalize, use the **[`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function:

```
select * 
from dp_deals as d 
  left join dp_business_locations as b 
    on FIND_IN_SET(b.businessLocID, d.dealBusinessLocations)
```

Then, read that article again. If the query is slow or if you have other problems with this table, then you'll know why:

**[`Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?

Yes, it is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**

Comment: +1 CSV in a database is pure evil and will send you straight to hell.

Comment: @Johan - Worse that that, it won't be straight to hell, it'll make you work your way the long route to get there!

Comment: I know csv field is a big problem, But i can't change the database schema. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use `find_in_set()`  instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dp_deals as d 
LEFT JOIN dp_business_locations as b 
       ON (FIND_IN_SET(b.businessLocID,d.dealBusinessLocations) > 0);
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Note that if you drop CSV and get out off hell you can use a simple join like:

```
SELECT d.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.dealBusinessLocation) as locations
FROM dp_deals as d 
LEFT JOIN dp_business_location as b 
       ON (d.dealBusinessLocation = b.businessLocID);
```

Which will be much much faster and normalized as a bonus.

Comment: I think you have the 2 parameters in reverse order.

Comment: I am bothered about csv issue, but i can't change the database design. find_in_set() is working fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `IN()` doesn't expect to get one string with lots of fields in it, but lots of fields.

With your function you are sending it this:

```
WHERE something IN ('\'21\',\'22\''); /* i.e. a single text containing "'21','22'" */
```

And not the expected

```
WHERE something IN ('21','22');
```

Comment: Plz check the output of the function posted above. ie. mysql> BusinessList( '21,22' )
BusinessList( '21,22' )
-----------------------
'21','22' . It returns the correct format.

Comment: @SijoKurian - Your string is indeed in the format you intended.  But the point @Cylindric's answer is trying to make is that it is still just one string.  It is *not* a list of numbers.  Just because a string happens to have the characters that represent numbers and commas, etc, it doesn't become a list of many items, it's just *one* string with all of those characters in it.  What you need to do is return a TABLE of *many* strings, instead of just one string.  Then you can do `WHERE x IN (SELECT * FROM function())`

Comment: As @Dems says, it is not.  You need to return *several* strings or numbers, and *not* one string that looks like several numbers with commas between.